# setting selected/deselected on buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the user to have the ability to select a book from my page and deselect it.

I also need to be able to keep an element selected when the user refreshes the page.

css:

```
button:focus {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

javascript:

```
function renderItemHtml(item) {
return `<button><div class="book"><img src="${item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}" class="thumbnails" 
alt="${item.singleTitle} by ${item.volumeInfo.authors[0]}" />
<div>
<h4>${item.volumeInfo.title}</h4>
<p><strong>${item.volumeInfo.authors}</strong></p>
<h8>${item.volumeInfo.description.slice(0, 140)}</h8> 
</div>
<br>
<h8>Pages:  ${item.volumeInfo.pageCount}</h8>
</div></button>`
```

}

Comment: If it is not for production and Server Side then you can use `localStorage`

Comment: @ShreyBhangale yes I've read that this would work but I don't know how to implement that into my code and it to change the selection

Comment: Do you want to select only one _book_ or multiple _books_ ?

Comment: @ShreyBhangale I just want to be able to select 1 book, with the ability to deselect it.
Also having the choice be remembered when the page is refreshed. Still struggling with it pal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the index of the active element and save that to localstorage with `click` Event.

```
<style>
button:focus {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
button.isActive{
    /*Your Stuff*/
}
</style>
<script>

function addActiveClass(activeBook, classname) {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(`.${classname}`);
    elems.forEach((elem)=>{
        elem.classList.remove(`${classname}`);
    });
    activeBook.classList.add(`${classname}`);
}

function findIndex(node) {
    let children = node.parentNode.childNodes;
    const childrenLength = children.length;
    let index = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < childrenLength; ++i) {
         if (children[i] === node) return index;
         if (children[i].nodeType === 1) ++index;
    }
    return -1;
}

function setActiveClass(elem, classname) {
    const getActiveBookIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("active-book"));
    let bookHolderDiv = elem[getActiveBookIndex].getElementByClassName("book");
    bookHolderDiv.classList.add(`${classname}`);
}

function renderItemHtml(item) {

    const bookSection = document.getElementById("bookSection");

    let btn = document.createElement("button");

    let bookHolder = document.createElement("div");
    let thumbnailCover = document.createElement("img");

    let titleHolderDiv = document.createElement("div");

    let bookTitle = document.createElement("h4");
    let bookAuthors = document.createElement("p");
    let bookDescription = document.createElement("h6");

    let breakLine = document.createElement("br");

    let bookPages = document.createElement("h6");

    bookHolder.classList.add("book");

    thumbnailCover.classList.add("thumbnails");

    thumbnailCover.src = `${item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}`;
    thumbnailCover.alt = `${item.singleTitle} by ${item.volumeInfo.authors[0]}`;

    bookTitle.innerText - `${item.volumeInfo.title}`;

    bookAuthors.style.fontWeight = `bold`;
    bookAuthors.innerText = `${item.volumeInfo.authors}`;

    bookDescription.innerText = `${item.volumeInfo.description.slice(0, 140)}`;

    bookPages.innerText = `${item.volumeInfo.pageCount}`;

    titleHolderDiv.appendChild(bookTitle);
    titleHolderDiv.appendChild(bookAuthors);
    titleHolderDiv.appendChild(bookDescription);

    bookHolder.appendChild(thumbnailCover);
    bookHolder.appendChild(titleHolderDiv);

    bookHolder.appendChild(breakLine);
    bookHolder.appendChild(bookPages);

    btn.appendChild(bookHolder);

    bookSection.appendChild(btn);

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("active-book", findIndex(btn));

        addActiveClass();
        setActiveClass(btn, `isActive`);
    });
}
</script>
```